# Automatically smooth line after slicer in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-2007

I need help in fixing the line graph to a smoothed line. It keeps on getting crooked after clicking/selecting a slicer.

I am trying to avoid VBA as it needs to be activated for it to be smoothed again but if there's a workaround the better.

Answer (score 1):

Formula
=AVERAGE(OFFSET($A$1, ROW()-2, 0, 3, 1))